# Swift: preferredStatusBarStyle() not called using SSASideMenu

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar, side-menu

I know there are many questions related to this but I have tried almost everything. I am using **SSASidemenu** and `preferredStatusBarStyle()` is calling every time while moving from one ViewController to another and I am able to set the color only once. But I need to show both light and dark status bar in different viewControllers. I have created a custom viewController class in which I need to show dark status bar and .light for others.

Can anyone tell me the solutions

Comment: i think you are almost there, when each controller appears you can set the status bar how you want for that controller, you can do it in `func viewDidAppear` - if you have to set it everytime it appears, that isn't a big deal, just part of the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set the status bar anytime one of your subclasses of `ViewController` appears, you can do so in the `viewDidAppear` method:

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

[viewDidAppear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear)

NOTE: You could also probably set it in `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` - that fires anytime the subviews need to be laid out, I'm just not sure if the status bar is technically a subview, you could test it out - `viewDidAppear` is most likely an acceptable choice.